# Asking the user to enter amount of items to an array

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm really new to Java and I am having some difficulty with the basics of arrays. Some help would be greatly appreciated :).

I created a program that asks the user to enter values into an array. The program then tells the user how many items are in the array, the even numbers that are in the array, the odd numbers in the array and the average of all the numbers in the array.

My problem is this: At present my program has a set number of values in the array which is 5 items. I want to change this so that the user can determine the amount of items they want in the array, and ask the user to continually add values to the array until they enter 'Q' to quit entering values so that the program can continue.

I do not want to modify my code, just the part where the user determines the amount of items in the array.

This is my code:

```
//main class
public class Even_number_array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    array_class obj=new array_class();
    obj.get_numbers();
    obj.set_arraylist();
    obj.set_numbers();
    obj.get_average_of_array();


}
}

//another class

import java.util.Scanner;

public class array_class {

private int[] arr=new int[5]; //here is where I would like to modify my code so 
                           //that the user can determine amount of items in array                                             


Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

public int[] get_numbers() //asks user to add items to array
{
  System.out.println("Please enter numbers for array :");
  for (int i=0; i<this.arr.length; i++)
  {
    this.arr[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
  }
    System.out.println("There are "+((arr.length))+ " numbers in array");
    return this.arr;
}

public void set_numbers() //Tells user what even & odd numbers are in array
{
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println("These even numbers were found in the array:");
 for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
 {
  if (arr[i]%2==0)
  {
   System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
   System.out.println();
  }
 }

 System.out.println("These odd numbers were found in the array:");
 for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
 {
  if ((arr[i]%2)!=0)
 {
   System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");      
  }
 }
}

public void set_arraylist() //Dispalys all items in array
{
 System.out.println("These are the numbers currently in your array: ");

 for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++ )
 {
  System.out.print(this.arr[i]+ " ");
 }
}

public double get_average_of_array() //Gets average of all items in array
{
 double sum=0;
 double average=0;

System.out.println();
System.out.println("the average is: ");
 for (int i=0; i<this.arr.length; i++)
 {     
  sum=sum+arr[i];
  average =sum/arr.length;

 }
  System.out.println(average);
  return average;
}
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You can't dynamically change the size of an array.  You have to create a new array everytime you want to change the size.  Use ArrayList.

Comment: @bro05 I want to change this part of my code completely so that the user will be able to determine the size of the array, is there no possible way to do this?

Comment: @bro05 I tried this, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public int[] get_numbers() {
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers for array :");
    int size = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] values = new int[size];   // create a new array with the given size
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        values[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("There are "+((values.length))+ " numbers in array");
    this.arr = values;
    return this.arr;
}
```

Comment: Note that the console will say "Please enter numbers for array :" and the first number they enter will actually be the size of the array, not the first number of the array. Would be confusing to an actual user.

Comment: I thought as much so I added something to stop the confusion. Thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i don't really get what you are asking but maybe you mean this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number");

    int[] array = new int[scanner.nextInt()];

    System.out.println(array.length);
```

Sorry i'm pretty bad in java only been learning it for 2 months now

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is the object you want. It has functions that allow you to append values at the end. It's a dynamic array in the sense that you can mutate it at will.

Answer (score 0):

Using an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of arrays would be the easiest way to accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.

Another option is to ask how many numbers the person plans on entering from the start.

If, for some weird reason, you are only trying to use arrays without asking the user how many numbers they want to enter... a third option would be to create a new array *(being one size larger than the previous array)* each time the user enters another number.

Some guidance for the last piece...

```
public int[] get_numbers() //asks user to add items to array
{
  System.out.println("Please enter numbers for array :");
  //Instead of this for loop, you will want a while loop. Similar to "while (userHasntEnteredQ)"
  for (int i=0; i<this.arr.length; i++)
  {
    //You will want to create a new array here.
    // int[] newArray = new int[this.arr.length + 1];
    // Then copy the values of this.arr to newArray
    // Then place the keyboard.nextInt() into the last spot of newArray
    // Then set this.arr to newArray
  }
    System.out.println("There are "+((arr.length))+ " numbers in array");
    return this.arr;
}
```

Comment: how would I accomplish the latter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to determine how many items are in the array, add this in to your code:

```
System.out.println("Enter the amount of items in the array:");
while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
    int i = keyboard.nextInt();
}
private int[] arr = new int[i];
```

However, you won't be able to add more items to the array than the user defined without getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so there is a better way to do this that uses something called an `ArrayList`. With an `ArrayList`, you don't have to worry about setting the size of the array before using it; it just expands automatically when new items are added unless you explicitly set a size for it. An `ArrayList` can be of any object, but to make it only for integers, declare it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

To add items to the `ArrayList`:

```
arr.add(item);
```

To read a value by its index:

```
arr.get(index);
```

To get the index of an item:

```
int index = arr.indexOf(item);
```

There is much more that you can do with an `ArrayList`. Read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know "ArrayList" existed but now that I do I'll try it out

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList();` will generate a warning _"The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<Integer>"_ ... use `ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();` or the Java 7 "diamond operator" `ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes, in that case use the diamond operator. If you put `Integer` on both sides it is redundant.